# How can I retrieve the value of the only item I have an a Dictionary (C#) in one line?

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can I retrieve the value of the only item I have an a Dictionary (C#) in one line?  Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use a variable instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
dictionary.Single().Value
```

`Single` throws an exception if the dictionary doesn't contain exactly one element (if you don't like this behavior, use `First()` instead). If you're sure you're going to put a single item in a dictionary, why aren't you simply using a variable?

Comment: Just for a test case. Is First() an extension method?

Comment: @Greg: Yes, it's an extension method declared in `System.Linq.Enumerable` class.